# sbt-proguard: make two jars

Tags: scala, sbt, proguard

I have the following requirement. I have a project with two packages:

```
com.interfaces
com.impl
```

I am using the sbt-proguard plugin shrink my project (I mainly need shrinking for com.impl, com.interfaces has almost no code). The thing is, I need com.interfaces needs to be in its own separate jar. Proguard by default puts everything in one jar, even if I separate com.interfaces into its own sbt-project (which I have no problem doing).

I am close to making a post-build script that just unzips the jar, and make two new jars with 7-zip, but I am sure there is a better solution :)

Answer (score 0):

ProGuard supports various types of filters on its input and output. For example:

```
-outjars interfaces.jar(com/interfaces/**)
-outjars impl.jar(com/impl/**)
-outjars remainder.jar
```

Or with separate input jars:

```
-injars  interfaces_in.jar
-outjars interfaces_out.jar
-injars  impl_in.jar
-outjars impl_out.jar
```

See the ProGuard manual > Examples > [Filtering the input and the output](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#filtering)

Unfortunately, I don't know if SBT supports these features.